# Cross-platform mobile application framework with mySQL?

Tags: mysql, frameworks, mobile, cross-platform

I've been looking into some mobile development frameworks lately. The app I want to develop looks more like a business app. I should be able to retrieve data from my MySQL database. As well just fetch normal data, but as well a log-in system.

I would set up a webservice in PHP that the mobile app could use to retrieve the data, but what's the most robust framework to make these kind of apps?

It's important that these frameworks are **free**.

I've taken a look at

**JMango**

At first sight, it doesn't look like it's able to do something like that really. It seems to have it's own scripting language, seems unlikely that it can meet such business needs.

**Rhomobile**

Seems like you need a license to even get it running, so doesn't seem an option either.

**phonegap**

Looks nice, but what frightens me is that all business logic is pumped into javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd vote for PhoneGap (disclaimer—I have contributed to this (a bit)).
PhoneGap puts the business logic in JavaScript as this is the only cross platform programming language. Other solutions conver/recompile code for each app.

Alternatively you could look at the Mono family of tools ([MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) & [MonoDroid](http://monodroid.net/)) which when combined with C#/VS2010 can be used to create apps for Windows Phone 7, iPhone & Android.

Comment: Thanks, that's something to discuss with my project leader. Do you use anything else from JS libraries? I assume jQuery or one of the others, but my eyes also stumbled on the jQuery mobile project, and as well on Sencha touch JS framework. I'll certainly put it on my list to have a look at it :)